# Unable to Compile MIT App Inventor App to APK

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, app-inventor

When I try to compile my App Inventor 2 app to APK, I get the following message:

[This is the error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2WSj.jpg)
[image]

[This is my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEemp.jpg)
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: I don´t know if this is the correct platform for AppInventor. It´s hard to analyze an app inventor app here, because there is no code. I also tried that in the beginning and now I have to say: Coding is more easy and faster after while, believe me. Anyway, in the error there is **line 511**....can see any line numbers?

Comment: Don't post screenshots, include the code

Comment: make sure, there are no red warnings before building the app... generally for questions like that it is better to ask in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest)... also don't hesitate to first  [do a search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/call$20to$20set$20and$20coerce$20property%7Csort:relevance) there...

Comment: where is line number 511?

Comment: The error message is **call to set and coerce property has too few arguments**, what about following [this link to get a list of similar questions in the forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/call$20to$20set$20and$20coerce$20property%7Csort:relevance) as already suggested?

Comment: You think I didn't looks already?!!!!!

Comment: You did not told us your searched for it...

Answer (score 0):

Go into the blocks editor in App Inventor 2. At the bottom left corner, there will be a warnings/hazards area. Click on "Show Warnings." This will tell you the problem.

Comment: Taifun: You should stop criticizing people and learners and try helping instead. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

To build the APK, click on your app, and then in the bar at the top of the page you should see the "build" button. Click on it and select "save APK to my computer" and that should work. If not, let me know!